# Is it OK to push changes to GitHub when the local Jekyll server is running?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have set up a small blog using Jekyll recently and had it hosted on GitHub Pages. Everything appears to be working fine. I make and test changes locally and then push them to GitHub using:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

which has also been working fine.

Sometimes, I push the changes when the local Jekyll server is running. Though I haven't had a problem until now, I am wondering if pushing the changes to GitHub when the Jekyll server is running is OK or even good practice.

I am using Jekyll 4.3.2 on macOS 13.3.1 at this time.

Comment: It's ok, I do it every day. The local server is just there to cross-check results from local changes.